# JPA native query with blob converting blob results to question marks when text contains multi languages

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

JPA native query with blob converting blob results to question marks when text contains multi languages like below. 
"description" : "??????"

Tried encoding like below. But still same issue.
String xmlFile=new String(xmlBytesArray, "UTF-8");

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found that issue is not with JPA native query but with JAXB unmarshaling.

After reading blob as string from query we are tring to unmarshall the XML directly using converted string from blob instead of directly passing the byte array.

Below is the fix for the problem.

```
public static Object unMarshaller(JAXBContext jc,byte[] byteArr) throws JAXBException{
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
        u.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
        Source input = new StreamSource(bais);
        return u.unmarshal(input);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your default system-encoding is not UTF-8 - you can change this for your java-process by setting a system-property:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Another possibility is that you have to add the encoding to your DB-Connection-String
for MySQL this would be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks Halko for your support. I have added the system property in my jboss standalone.xml but still same issue.